# Excel VBA - Click on sort button or select from dropdown list on IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, dropdown

I am trying to obtain some data pertaining to session "T" in a html using VBA. There are 2 ways to do this:

1. to select "T" from dropdown list under "Trading Session"
2. to click on the header "Session" and sort the data

Below is the code, which doesn't work

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim dropdown As Object

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate "https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/delayed-prices-futures?cc=AJ&category=fx"
        Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
      
    Set dropdown = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("sgx-input-control sgx-input-select-filter")(2)
        dropdown.Focus
        dropdown.selectedIndex = 1    *'Error Msg "Object doesn't support this property or method"*
        dropdown.FireEvent ("onchange")

  ie.Quit
```

In addition, I've also tried method 2 using the following lines, but nothing happens (list not sorted but no error too):

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("sgx-table-header-wrapper")(0).Click
```

I am new to coding, I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: The element in which you are trying to set the value is readonly. Also it is not actual select dropdown. So it is not possible to set its value or fire change event. It has a css class isactive when user click on that element but there is not HTML code for that in the source code. So because of this reason it is hard to select the T from the dropdown and update the data. If possible for you then try to click on down arrow one time using VBA code to sort the T value data.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tried to click on the down arrow using VBA to sort the T value data, but nothing happens when I click on the heading.

Comment: It will be hard to sort the table on the site. If you are trying to copy the table data then you can do it first and sort the data later after you paste the data to the Excel. This can be workaround for the said issue.

Comment: The webpage only allows first 26 rows to be downloaded, sorting after I paste the data to Excel means I will only get 13 rows of useful data (as I do not need T+1) which is not enough for me. Therefore, I need to sort before downloading the data. I tried using Chrome instead of IE to sort the data with the following code: `ie.FindElementByClass("sgx-table-header-sort-button").Click` .It works well, but I then have a problem to scrape the data in rows and columns in Excel.

Comment: I suggest try to make a test with the Selenium web driver. Then try to click on the down arrow to sort the data. See whether it is working or not. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/

Comment: I tested Selenium web driver, it works to sort the data. However, i cant scrape the data into Excel.

Comment: As a last option, you can try to contact that site to know whether they can provide any API to their users to fetch the data from their site.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getelementsbyname`

```
ie.document.getelementsbyname("trading-session")(1).Value = "T"
```

You can get the name `trading-session` by right clicking on the dropdown and selecting "inspect element"

[image]

Also since the trading session only has "T" now then there is no point of sorting it using that header?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code changed the value of the "trading session" from "All" to "T" temporarily, but the data did not change.

Comment: You are right that if I can change the trading session to "T", I don't need to sort the header.